# En Java saber el maximo de más de dos enteros

Tags: java, math

quisiera saber si hay alguna formasi usar condicionales de saber el valor maximo de más de dos números.
Con 
`int resultado = Math.max(valor1,valor2);`
Solo me deja dos valores
Gracias

Answer (score 4):

Una manera en la que puedes hacerlo por ejemplo con tres números sería así:

```
int valor1 = entrada.nextInt();
int valor2 = entrada.nextInt();
int valor3 = entrada.nextInt();
int resultado = Math.max(Math.max(valor1, valor2), valor3);
```

**EDIT**

Te pongo un ejemplo donde genero 10 numero aleatorios y los guardo en un array. Después compruebo cual de esos valores es el mayor y lo guardo en una variable.

```
public class MaxNumber{
    public static int maxNumber = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] arrayNumber = new int[10];

        for(int i = 0; i < arrayNumber.length; i++){
            int number = (int)(Math.random()*10+1);
            arrayNumber[i] = number;
            System.out.println(number);

            if(arrayNumber[i] > maxNumber){
                maxNumber = arrayNumber[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The number max is: "+ maxNumber);
    }
}
```

Espero que pueda servirte!

Comment: Gracias Mario¿y si tengo 10 valores?

Comment: @Daniel He actualizado mi respuesta y he añadido un ejemplo en el que puedes guiarte y hacerte una idea.

Comment: @ Mario Yo me referia a `int resultado = Math.max(Math.max(valor1, valor2, valor3,valor4,valor5);` y que me diese el maximo de los que introdujese, al parecer solo se pueden dos valores o el tercero como bien pusiste tu.perdón pero estoy empezando y tengo muchas dudas